# what is the difference between tensorflow concat() and concatenate()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the difference (functionally) between `tf.concat()` and `tf.keras.layers.concatenate()`?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate

Also, what is the difference between `tf.nn.conv2d` and `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d

Comment: The ones with `layer` are layers used in a model, with trainable weights in the case of `Conv2D`. The other functions are doing the same operations, just directly on input tensors. `tf.nn.conv2d` has no learnable kernel, but needs the kernel weights as input too.